# Application for Start Menu > Programs Menu to Organize in Categories, without damaging the Programs Menu?

Tags: gui, windows-8, menu, classification, shell-extension

Now, I use the following:

- **Launchy**: Quick launch *tiny/ portable apps/ tools* by **"Name"** (issue when can't remember name)
- **Classic Shell**: For Win 7/ 2000 Classic Menu & Explorer in Win 8.1 & avoid Metro with these:

**2 Column Option + Classic Skin**: `Start Menu > Programs > Classic Shell > ..Menu Items`

[image: Classic Shell 2 Column Programs]

With so many programs & their names, it's hard to remember which does what. And when wanting to do certain work, **it'd be good to see "same category" applications together / nearby to trigger my memory of which ones to use and how for what I have in mind**.

Now, I know that it's possible to Create Folders in this structure, drag & drop (copy/ move) and rearrange all of the folders/ menu items i.e. Program Shortcuts. Did it in the past; 2000/ XP days.

But, that means destroying/ interfering with part of what the Windows System created in Programs Menu, remembers and would result in inconsistencies, leaves behind residuals when un-installing and so on, needing lots of manual cleanup.

It also, means lot of manual creation at the start and when new programs are installed.

I'd like an application that:

- Leverages the Structure created by Windows
- An Overlay mechanism or Creates its own copy/ syncs with this structure
- Provides Buckets/ Categories to ASSIGN/ UNASSIGN existing and new Programs & their SubMenus.
- Program that does not destroy whatever structure Windows creates (Installations) or removes (Uninstalls) and also not interfering with it.
- It could be invoked from the same place in UI, or anywhere else
- It could "visually" replace the Programs Menu or Create its own invoked from elsewhere on Screen
- Bonus, if it can add new Programs into "New Uncategorized" type of Bucket

### **Ideas & Examples I like (with some comments/ shortcomings)**

---

**Mint Linux Cinnamon**: Provides Category Folders/ Buckets for Programs as well as ability to see All programs. But, it does not do cascaded menus like Windows/ Classic

[image: Mint Linux Cinnamon Menu]

[**Configurable Menu**: Install the best menu for Linux Mint 17/17.1 Cinnamon](http://linuxbsdos.com/2014/12/02/configurable-menu-install-the-best-menu-for-linux-mint-1717-1-cinnamon/)
An add on top of Cinnamon that gives a lot of configurable varieties for the Menu:
[image: Configurable Menu Varieties]

---

**SyMenu:** Provides a separate, non overlay mechanism to create your own Menu > Sub Menu system/ structure. Does not import, sync or have any relation with Windows Menu. Also, that means having to add each ".exe" by hand.

A great feature for it would've been the ability to "replicate" or "link" the specific "application program's" entire "installed sub-folder menu" under "Categories buckets". And it would be great to "assign/ move/ change" Program <> Category assignment.

Such a Program <> Category overlay assignment system is present in Revo Uninstaller Pro

[image: SyMenu 1]
[image: SyMenu 2]
[image: SyMenu 3]
[image: SyMenu Config]